# Sorting file contents and the file size 4gb and ram 2 gb

Tags: java, sorting, memory

How to sort the contents in the text file.But The file size 4 GB and my System RAM 2 GB.If i am trying sorting context it degrade system performa.Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting huge Number of Integers from hard disk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012523/sorting-huge-number-of-integers-from-hard-disk)

Comment: And also duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358087/sort-with-the-limited-memory

Answer (score 2):

The approach you have to follow is 
[External Sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting)

Typically, you divide the file into small blocks, sort each block in RAM, and then merge the result.

So, You sort small chunks of data first, write it back to disk and than iterate over those to sort all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what kind of data is stored in the text file? how do you access it? Can it be indexed by some key?

If it is just a file of words you can easily divide the file in K chunks of data, order it separatedly, and then merge them all together in another final sorted file.